# Configure Quartus 2 Simulator to run for longer

Tags: quartus-ii

My simulation in Quartus 2 finishes at 1uS. How can I get it to go on for longer? This is because my test hasn't finished by this point so I can't tell whether or not my part is successful or not with large numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the vector waveform file, then go to Edit->"End Time." From there, you can adjust when your simulation ends.